# Проверка на несуществование в Java

Tags: java

Подскажите, правильно ли использовать ! (восклицательный знак) для проверки несуществования результатов.

```
if (!rs.next()) {
   System.out.println("Данные не найдены");
} else {
   System.out.println("что-то нашли");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрим документацию по ResultSet:

> Returns: **true** if the new current row
> is valid; **false** if there are no more
> rows

Вывод: вполне правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Все правильно, обычно с resultset я использую код такого вида:

```
while (resultset.next())
{
    // do something with retrieved data
}

или

if (!resultset.next())
{
    // в зависимости от логики, вместо ошибки можно выводить сообщение в лог
    throw new SomeError("No data found");
}

// do something with retrieved data
```